# Displaying Chinese characters on a form from an INI File

Tags: encoding, ini, asianfonts

My plugin reads the control caption text from an INI file (ANSI as UTF-8 encoding) in order to display multiple languages. Key point being it is a plugin, I have no control nor ability to change this INI file format or file type.

They are currently being read into my plugin with `TINIFile.ReadString` and stored as a `string`. I can modify this (data type, read method, etc) as needed.

The main application reads from its own application language files that are UCS-2 Little Endian encoded as a TXT file. These display fine when the language is changed, even when the Windows OS is kept in English (in other words no OS locale changes need to be made for the application to switch display languages).

My plugin's form cannot display Asian characters (Chinese, Japanese, Korean, etc). English language is fine.

[image: Close up of plugin's form while attempting to display Chinese characters]

I have tried various fonts, using various combinations of `AnsiString`, `String`, etc. What am I missing to be able to display Asian characters on the form? I have not found a similar question to what I'm trying to do specifically with how my language text is being read into the plugin.

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: Can you use Xml instead of an Ini file? Xml allows to specify which encoding you are using, hence it should be read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the .INI file reader does not interpret the contents of the values, and allows all values through transparently, then you need to map the strings into one with the correct locale.

There is a similar question at [Delphi 2010: how do I convert a UTF8-encoded PAnsiChar to a UnicodeString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472233/delphi-2010-how-do-i-convert-a-utf8-encoded-pansichar-to-a-unicodestring) that explains how to do the conversion. You may need to extract the contents into a [RawByteString](http://www.micro-isv.asia/2008/08/using-rawbytestring-effectively/) to avoid the implicit conversions.